# Connect local SQL Server from WSL2 (Ubuntu)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I started to develop a .NET Core Web API application with SQL Server. I use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (I store the files in the Ubuntu server).

Unfortunately I can't connect to SQL Server which is installed on Windows 10.

I enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server configuration but I don't know which is the correct connection string.

Comment: We can't see your screen and don't know your network setup. Please edit your question to include the connection string (anonymize the server address, username and password as required) as well as the full and complete error message you're getting - as text.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65625762/11810933), but as was mentioned, it's hard to know for sure without more detail in your question.  If the linked question/answer help you, then please remember to upvote both, and close out your question here.  Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look over here:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4619

Answer (score 4):

There is long issue that windows services are not accessible from WSL - [github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4619)
Making long story short, you need to use IP address of your windows machine as server.

You can take it multiple ways e.g. calling this command from Windows commandline

```
ipconfig /all
```

and taking your IP address.

You need to enable 1433 port to be accessible from WSL in Windows Defender:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=WSL_SQL dir=in protocol=tcp action=allow localport=1433 remoteip=localsubnet profile=any
```

Over [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585) there is an issue.
Opening concrete port works for me.

From your WSL terminal you can verify that you can access sql using e.g. telnet.

```
telnet <windows_host_ip> 1433
```

It should return something like this:

```
Trying <windows_host_ip>...
Connected to <windows_host_ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If it doesn't work please also verify that you have TCP service enabled in you SQL Configuration Manager
-> here you can find guidance for it -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818373/how-do-i-connect-to-a-local-windows-sql-server-instance-from-wsl)

Comment: This can be simplified by using the mDNS name `$(hostname).local` instead of IP address.  Under most recent (3-4 years, at least) Windows releases, mDNS will return the correct (Hyper-V switch) address that can be used to access Windows services via WSL.  See [my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but it doesn't work for me.  -> 
nc -zv "$(hostname).local" 1433
nc: getaddrinfo for host "R90VXSZR.local" port 1433: Name or service not known

and ->
nc -zv <windows_ip> 1433
Connection to 192.168.1.13 1433 port [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!

Any clues?

Comment: What's your `uname -a` show?

Comment: Linux R90VXSZR 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Aug 25 23:20:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Very odd.  You're the second person who has reported it hasn't worked, so I'd love to know what the difference is.  Just to confirm, R90VXSZR is also the Windows "Computer Name", right?

Comment: Yes - this is my Windows host name.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds any clues on that?

Comment: Well, I re-read your post, and I'm not sure mDNS would be any "easier" in this case anyway.  But I'm still wondering also why it isn't working for you.  Is there a chance you've turned off the WSL `/etc/resolv.conf` auto-generation?  That might do it, since it's the Windows resolver that would handle local mDNS.

Comment: I am modifying `/etc/resolv.conf` while it doesn't resolve external addresses. It looks like this way: 
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.28.160.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: That might be it - Where is `172.28.160.1` coming from?  The Hyper-V switch (also the resolver) address changes each time WSL restarts.  Is that address the same that is reported if you run `ip route show default | awk '{print $3}'`?

Comment: It is automatically generated via `wsl` - it's the same as result of `ip route...`.
During start I am adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Ok, well that should still work, I would think.  Still noodling, then ...

Comment: Will be thankful if you will bring some light to it :) Thanks @NotTheDr01ds

Comment: Hmm.  I did have another thought - does mDNS (`ping R90VXSZR.local`) work in PowerShell?

Comment: Yup from PowerShell it works: ping -4 R90VXSZR.local gives output Pinging R90VXSZR.<company-domain> [172.24.0.1] with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 172.24.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Any thought?